# log4j creating .tmp file for logs randomly

Tags: java, log4j, java.util.logging

My application log configuration is as follows

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,file
# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/mylocation/app.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=2048MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

It creates log file and zip it everyday at midnight but randomly I can observe that .tmp files are created in my log folder and no zip created for that day.
Has some one observed the similar behavior ?
Or any possible reason for this so that I can handle that or change my log configuration accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RollingFileAppender` oly creates a new logfile if the MaxFileZize is reached not every day.

> RollingFileAppender extends FileAppender to backup the log files when they reach a certain size.

Also the createion of the zip file is not done by log4j. There must be an other Prozess, which will zip the logfiles.

If you need a new logfile every day, you have to use the `DailyRollingFileAppender`

> DailyRollingFileAppender extends FileAppender so that the underlying file is rolled over at a user chosen frequency